# why does wolframscript start an instance of Mathematica frontend?

Tags: performance-tuning, scripting

The following wls file surprisingly creates an instance of Mathematica (v12.1) on OS X 10.15.7:

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript
plato = "Icosahedron";
SetDirectory["./hp-d-wbps-t6-s1-wls/"];

Range2[from_, to_, step_] := 
  {#, Length@#} &[
  Join[Range[from, to, step], Range[to - step, from + step, -step]]
];
  
Get["../../../../HyperPlatonics.m"];

Block[
    {
       full = Range2[.1, 1.5, .01],
       viewpoints
    },
  viewpoints = 
   Table[
       2.9 {2.5 Cos@\[Phi], 2 Sin@\[Phi], .3 Sin@\[Phi]}, 
       {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/(Last[full] - 1)}
   ];
  Map[
   Export[
     "img" <> IntegerString[# , 10, 6] <> ".jpg",
     WarpedBeamedPlatonicSolid[
          plato,
          3, .9, .7, {5, 5},
          First[full][[#]],
          ViewVector -> {viewpoints[[#]], {0, 0, 0}},
          ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1},
          ViewAngle -> 35 Degree,
          ImageSize -> Large
      ]
   ] &,
   Range[Last@full]
  ]
];
```

Why does this happen?
Any chance to suppress this behavior?

Comment: "Any chance to suppress this behavior?" I don't think so, but why do you want to suppress it? If you ask about the actual problem that the FE is causing, there may be a solution. As for exporting graphics without the FE—that is not possible.

Comment: @Szabolcs: "exporting graphics without FE not possible" answers the question - tnx 1m

Comment: I'm not 100% clear about what exactly the FE is required for. Converting a `Graphics[...]` to a bitmap definitely relies on the FE (this is your case). However, if you already have a bitmap, you can export that without the FE. Technically, it's not the exporting but rasterization/rendering that needs the FE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Certain functionality, most notably rasterizing graphics, is implemented by the front end. In your case it is the JPEG export that triggers this.

Comment: Would the function `UsingFrontEnd` help in this case?